# "Text" column still showing data as "[BLOB - 225B]" after converting from Blob to Text?

Tags: mysql, database, type-conversion

On one of my sites, I have a table that originally was of type `Blob`.  Via **phpMyAdmin**, I went to the "Structure" of that specific column, and changed it to `Text`.

Now, under the "Structure" of the table, that column correctly shows up as `Text` instead of `Blob`, but when I actually click to "Browse" the rows of that table, every new and old row in that column is still showing up as `[BLOB - 225B]` rather than showing the Text contained within it.

This is making me think that the conversion wasn't done correctly since, if I'm not mistaken, a column with type `Text` should show its contents rather than the standard `[BLOB - 225B]`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: @eggyal:  I actually did this conversion a while ago, but only noticed today that the column is still showing values as `[BLOB - 225B]` when browsing it, and I have logged in and out of phpMyAdmin several times since then, so I don't think that's it.  Any other ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that since TEXT and BLOB differ only in sorting and collation, they are internally the same.  Did you try creating a new table with a TEXT column to see how it is displayed?

Comment: @Jim: As you hinted, the issue was with collation.  It was set to `utf8_bin`.  I changed it to `utf8_general_ci` and it displays the actual text contents now.  Could you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that since TEXT and BLOB differ only in sorting and collation, they are internally the same.  Check the collation.

Comment: As you hinted, the issue was with collation. It was set to `utf8_bin`. I changed it to `utf8_general_ci` and it displays the actual text contents now.  Thanks!